# PostgresSQL dump version recognition Bash script

Tags: bash, scripts, postgresql

I often recreate variuos customer databases on local dockers
to test new ERP functionalities in the development environment
So, PostgreSQL dump file usually starts with:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 13.3 (Ubuntu 13.3-1.pgdg20.04+1)
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1)
...
```

Thats why my bash script 'restorefromdump.sh' (building temporary docker
of the postgresql server appropriate version for dump file handling)
starts with:

```
#!/bin/bash
DBDUMP=$1
DUMPFROM=$(grep "^-- Dumped.*from " "$DBDUMP")
DUMPVERSION_inclSpaces=$(grep -o '^-- Dumped from.*(' "$DBDUMP" | grep -o -E '[0-9*.]+[^version]')
DUMPVERSION="$(echo -e "${DUMPVERSION_inclSpaces}" | tr -d '[:space:]')"
REMOTEPGVER=postgres:$DUMPVERSION
# calls 'buildtmpdocker' function to build temporary postgres docker 
buildtmpdocker $REMOTEPGVER 
...
```

After direct command './restorefromdump.sh *.dmp' Seems to be working effectively - it recognises dump version correctly,
but maybe there are better ways?
Are you used to recognise version inside dump file with Bash script?

Comment: What is the regex `[0-9*.]+[^version]` supposed to be doing according to you?

Comment: it finds numbers before 'version' string - example:

| $ nano testfile

| content: 'asw123version'

| after save the 'testfile'

| $ grep -o -E '[0-9*.]+[^version]' testfile

| result: '123'

Comment: it finds ONLY numbers :)

Comment: I don't know how you came up with that, but no, that's not what that regex does. It looks for one or more instances of digits, `*` or `.` followed by anything other than the letters `e`, `i`, `n`, `o`, `r`, `s`, `v`.

Comment: So, the conclusion is...  What is your opinion? Is my way wrong to get the target: number of PostgreSQL version including points?